# Toggle click upto 4 time works fine but after that from 6th click not works well

Tags: jquery

First click on link 1, it move 100px towards right and arrow shows.
Second click on link 2, it move 100px towards right, link 1 move backward and till arrow visible.
Third click on link 3, it move 100px towards right, link 2 move backward and till arrow visible.
Fourth click on link 4, it move 100px towards right, link 3 move backward and till arrow visible.
Then fifth click on link 4, it move backward and arrow disappear.

It fine but when I click next time, it not work and when click further next time 7th time, it work and next time not work and so on.

I expect when links move towards right arrow show and when links move back arrow hide.

```js
$('.nav ul li').click(function() {
  var clicks = $(this).data('clicks');
  
  if (clicks) {
    $(this).animate({right:0});
    $('.arrow').css({'opacity':'0'});
  } else {
    $(this).css({'position':'relative'}).animate({right:100},function(){
      $('.nav ul li').not(this).animate({right:0});
    });
    $('.arrow').css({'opacity':'1'});
  }

  $(this).data("clicks", !clicks);
});
```

```css
.nav {width:  100px; position: absolute; right: 40px; }
.nav ul li:hover {color: #fff;}
.arrow {
    position: absolute;
    right: 150px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-name: arrowAnimation;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-name: arrow-animation;
    animation-duration: 1s
}
@-webkit-keyframes arrowAnimation {
    from { top:10%; opacity:0 }
    to { top:18%; opacity:1 }
}
@keyframes arrowAnimation {
    from { top:10%; opacity:0 }
    to { top:18%; opacity:1 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
  </ul>
  <span class="arrow"><img src="images/arrow.png" alt="arrow" /></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, the blow works.

Although if I were you, I'd set the transition speed and animation for the arrow in the jQuery as well.

```
$('.nav ul li').click(function() {

  if($(this).css('right') !== '100px') {
    if($('.arrow').css('opacity') == '0') {
      $('.arrow').css({'opacity':'1'});
    }


    $(this).css({'position':'relative'}).animate({right:100},function(){
      $('.nav ul li').not(this).animate({right:0});
    })
  }
  else {
    $(this).animate({right:0})
    $('.arrow').css({'opacity':'0'});
  }

});
```

https://jsbin.com/guwahizesi/edit?html,css,js,console,output